# error "Access is Denied." FINDSTR: Cannot Open doh

Tags: batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

```
@echo off
cls
schtasks /query > doh

findstr /B /I %No% "imp" doh >nul

if %errorlevel%==0 goto :mycode

goto :createsch

:mycode
:top
start iexplore.exe C:\Users\Elmer\Desktop\Contacts\web.html
timeout 300
goto top

:createsch

Schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 5 /tn imp /tr %~dp0\..\desktop/newgv1.bat
"AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" >nul
del doh >nul
```

this is code what i am trying to do is create a task of same batch file and once create run a code.
when i run this code manually it runns fine.
but when task schedular run it automaticall as we create it , it give an error "Access is Denied." FINDSTR: Cannot Open doh

Comment: Use full paths for all files. When programming you either need to **fully understand** the environment or specify **exactly** what you want. You are probably trying to write to System32 folder.

Comment: Use concepts like `command > "%userprofile%\doh.txt"` or `command > "%temp\doh.txt"`. See `set` and `set /?`.

Comment: This not working i am sorry

Comment: That's an adult reply.